# Java spring pass id to url in template

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to match this pattern: `@RequestMapping("/hike/{id}")`, example url would be localhost:8080/hike/1

So in my template I have this line: `@{/hike/{id}(id=${hike.id})}` which is creating wrong url. Does anyone know how to adjust this line to create urls according to the RequestMapping?

EDIT:

Here is my controller that I'm working with:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "hike/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hikeId(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model){
        Hike hike = hikeService.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Hike Id"));
        model.addAttribute("hikes", hike);
        return "Welcome";
    }
```

EDIT:

my href wasnt th:href, but it is now and it is still not working. My template looks like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr th:each="hike : ${hikes}">
    <td th:text="${hike.name}"></td>
    <td><a th:href="@{/hike/${hike.id}}">SELECT</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What is the generated URL?  Are you using GET, not POST?

Comment: This was my generated URL http://localhost:8080/@%7B/hike/%7Bid%7D(id=$%7Bhike.id%7D)%7D

Comment: are you using th:href not href?

Comment: actually I wasnt! now I am and I´m still getting an error. URL is: http://localhost:8080/hike/$%7Bhike.id%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the URL with

```
<a th:href="@{/hike/{id}/(id=${hike.id})}">SELECT</a>
```

or

```
<a th:href="@{|/hike/${hike.id}|}">SELECT</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
If Controller like this: 

@RequestMapping(value="hike/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
             System.out.println("ID"+id);
        return "ID found"+id;
}



Then template willbe:

 <a th:href="@{'/hike/' + ${hike.id}}">Find by Id</a>
```

OR

```
**Controller:**

    @GetMapping(value="/hike/find-by-id")
    public String restore(Model model, @RequestParam Long id){
            System.out.println("ID"+id);
        return "ID found"+id;
    }


**Template:**

  <a type="button" th:href="@{/hike/find-by-id(id=${hike.id})}">Find by Id</a>
```

Comment: Hey I edited my question to show the controller I am using, I don't have to change the controller much cause it works to write URL by hand, e.g. localhost:8080/hike/1 shows me hike with id=1. 

So I tried your template: `@{'/hike/' + ${hike.id}}` it didnt work and returned url: http://localhost:8080/@%7B'/hike/'%20+%20$%7Bhike.id%7D%7D